# How to reset 3 guesses counter

Tags: python

I'm writing a quiz in Python where the user has 3 tries to get each answer right. It counts down fine to 0, but when it goes to the next question, it keeps counting down and doesn't reset to 3 guesses ie second question, answer is wrong and it says "You have -1 guesses left", "You have -2 guesses left" etc. How can I get it to reset to 3 tries for each new question? Variables are set at the top, code running is in def wrong_answer. Code below:

```
score = 0
max_guesses = 3

def quiz(riddle):

    counter = 0

    while counter < 3:
        answer = input(riddle["question"] + " ")

        if right_answer(answer, riddle):
            global score
            score += 1
            print("Correct! Well done.\nYour score is",score)
            break

        else: 
            wrong_answer(answer)
            print("Your score is",score)
            counter +=1

def right_answer(answer, riddle):
    return answer == riddle["answer"]

def wrong_answer(answer): 
    if answer != riddle["answer"]:
        global max_guesses
        max_guesses -= 1
        print("Sorry", answer, "is wrong.")
        print ("You have", max_guesses, "guesses left")

with open("riddles.json") as riddles_file:
    riddles = json.load(riddles_file)

for riddle in riddles:
    quiz(riddle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting the variables max_guesses and counter mixed up. Try like this

```
score = 0
max_guesses = 3

def quiz(riddle):

    counter = 0

    while counter < max_guesses:
        answer = input(riddle["question"] + " ")

        if right_answer(answer, riddle):
            global score
            score += 1
            print("Correct! Well done.\n Your score is",score)
        else:
            counter +=1
            wrong_answer(answer, counter)
            print("Your score is",score)


def right_answer(answer, riddle):
    return answer == riddle["answer"]

def wrong_answer(answer, counter): 
    if answer != riddle["answer"]:
        print("Sorry", answer, "is wrong.")
        print ("You have", max_guesses - counter, " guesses left")

with open("riddles.json") as riddles_file:
    riddles = json.load(riddles_file)

for riddle in riddles:
    quiz(riddle)
```

Comment: This won't work. The variable `counter` is undefined in `wrong_answer`.  You need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks Ian McGarry and Paul Cornelius. I did notice it was throwing me an error but putting it in as an argument rectified the problem. Thanks very much for both your help!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Amended.